# What limits the length of a cable?

Tags: amplifier, signal, cables, latency

As far as I can see this question has not been asked up to now but I'm not quite sure though I'm not an engineer..
But anyhow: Which parameters limit the length of a cable? On the one hand I know there are very long cables out there (e.g. internet cables in the oceans) and on the other often pc devices only support a few meter of cables. 
So what is the restriction and how can I circumvent it?

This is a general question and in specific I would like to know: Are there options to extend an usb or hdmi cable? I guess the major aspect concerns latency but I guess there might be any repeater or amplifiers or stuff like that? 
And does latency decrease significantly by the length? I also believe that this cannot be such an influence since I think houses/buildings have also different dsl cable lengths to the next node and so on?

I know the resistance increases with the length but this cannot be the only parameter due to the mentioned applications, described above.

**The specific background of my question is**: Is it possible to extend the cable of the receiver box of vr glasses (vive) to the PC?

Comment: I mean, your first paragraph already answers your question: The physical requirements for a cable depend on what you need to do with that cable. There's no general answer. In many applications (or: in most), latency doesn't matter, as it's in the range of distance · speed of light, so I think you've got that wrong. So, look at a *specific* use for a cable (Megawatts of power? Terabits per second? TV signals? Gigabits per second? A few bytes a day?), if possible even a specific standard (PCIexpress, DVB-C, 10 GBase-T ethernet, or maybe just an interface for heating controllers?) first.

Comment: You're basically expecting an answer that is *all* of transmission line theory and practice. That'd fill whole bookshelves, if not libraries, so let's take this slow and start with something specific. I think a single answer for a specific standard would give you enough info to ask better general questions, but I can't take the task of first focusing on  a single thing off your shoulder.

Comment: Focus your question on what you want to know instead of mentioning oceanic cables. Modern oceanic cables use optical fibres so they work in a completely different way from your average PC cable. Google for "USB/HDMI extender" and see what you find. Stop mentioning latency when it is so obvious you do not understand latency at all. The real reason USB and PC cables can only be a certain lenght is **signal integrity**. With longer cables the data cannot be transferred as reliably anymore.

Comment: Ok, at first thank you! I would like to begin with my peculiar purpose: I have a Vive glasses but I would like to extend the hdmi cable from the receiver box to the PC. Is there a possibility to do that?

Comment: So, please **edit** your question to focus on that. People won't read the comments to figure out what you're talking about.

Comment: and then, that's a **completely** different question than your title. You ask for *what* the physical limitations are, and then you mention that you actually wonder whether you can extend an HDMI cable. Which you can, as looking online for "HDMI extension cords" would've told you.

Comment: But do they regard the latency?

Comment: The latency of the cable is insignificant in comparison to the latency of the display device processing the signals and updating the display. The signals travel down the cable at a significant fraction of the speed of light, do you worry about the time it takes the light to get from the screen to your eyes?

Comment: @Ben: generally speaking the very most important factors that limit the length of a a cable are conductor cross section and volume.

Comment: Who are "they" ? You confuse everyone and yourself here with this "latency". You **think** that the cables delay the HDMI signal so much that there will be a noticeable time delay between the image in the PC and the image in your glasses. **That delay is not due to the cables**. The HDMI signal travels at the speed of light (almost) through the cables. That delay cannot be noticed by humans or even bees. The latency you refer to is **software related** and has **nothing** to do with cables.

Comment: You basically just needed to google a bit so that you would have found: https://www.cablestogo.com/learning/how-to/extend-hdmi-signal-video  This is the solution you seek and now that it is clear what you really wanted to ask this has turned into a **shopping** question which is **off Topic**. Also -1 for bringing up useless points which are unrelated to your real issue you have.

Comment: Thank you all! Transmission in hdmi is done via light? So I can extend a hdmi cable as much as I want??

@Bimpelrekkie "They" refered to the hdmi extension cords.

Comment: No the electrical HDMI signals travel at **light speed**. Perhaps you should just forget about **how** things work as you're only confusing yourself.

Comment: You mean a regular cable has a signal speed which is of the speed of light?
P.S.: I guess not to try to understand things is not helping anyone in the world..

Comment: @Ben The signals don't travel at a speed of light but fairly close to it. The exact speed depends on the cable used. The percentage of light speed that the signal travels at is known as the velocity factor of the cable, values are typically 50% to 85%. I can't find a value for HDMI off hand but I'd assume it's in the same range ballpark as Cat-5e network cable which is around 64%. So the signal will travel at roughly 2e8 m/s or just under 90 million miles per hour.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks! On https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Extenders there is written how to extend a cable. Also that there are devices which convert the signal to light so you can bridge astounding 300 meters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of limitations, travel time isn't normally one of them.
Here are some non-technical descriptions of limitations you can hit. Obviously as with all non-technical descriptions of technical matters they aren't perfect but should give you the general idea.

Firstly all wires have a resistance, the resistance of the cable will decrease any voltage that is applied to to. If the cable is too long the voltages will drop to the point where you can't reliably tell the difference between different signals. For cables that also supply power such as USB this problem is even worse.

Secondly cables act as antennas, the longer the cable the more noise it will pick up. This again makes it hard to distinguish between different signals especially when combined with the signal drop due to the cable resistance.

Thirdly cables have inductance and capacitance, these will round any edges of the signals and spread them out over time, nice square digital signals will become more rounded as they travel along the cable. This means that for longer cables you have to slow the data rate down in order for it to be avoid being smoothed out into nothing by the time it gets to the other end.

Comment: Example of where travel time is critical: Fast Ethernet depends on the duration of a packet being more than the latency of the cable, and  this is an important limitation on cable length.

Comment: Also any parallel bus where you want all the data to be clocked in by the same clock edge, you'd better pay attention to getting the same latency on all the data lines.